# Problems with a commutative diagram (tag above the arrow)

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I wrote the following diagram:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
& D \arrow[d,"f"] \arrow[dl, dashrightarrow, "F"] \\
M \arrow[r,"\phi"] & N
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

I want to know if there's a way to put the function $F$ above the dashrightarrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `swap`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
& D \arrow[d,"f"] \arrow[dl, dashrightarrow, "F"] \\
M \arrow[r,"\phi"] & N
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
& D \arrow[d,"f"] \arrow[dl, dashrightarrow, swap, "F"] \\
M \arrow[r,"\phi"] & N
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Imagine an arrow like a river, with the arrow tip being the mouth; then by default the label is placed along the left bank; with `swap` you put it along the right bank.

Comment: @MiguelRomán You can even have two labels: `\arrow[d,"a",swap,"b"]`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
& D \arrow[d,"f"] \arrow[dl,dashrightarrow, "F"'] \\
M \arrow[r,"\phi"] & N
\end{tikzcd}
    \end{document}
```

Trick is use `"F"'`.

[image]

Comment: @egreg, it is shown in the example on the bottom of the second page of package documentation (probably is mentioned also later but till to now I didn't read it further :-) ).

Comment: Yes, I saw it by searching for `"’` and not `"'`. Nice trick, but I still think `swap` to be more readable. I'll upvote tomorrow (votes ended for the day).